# Windows .bat File - How to make user input invisible on the command line?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a .bat file taking input from the user. I wish this input to be invisible as the user types it for security. The input is the user's password so it's important it cannot be seen by people looking over their shoulder.

The script right now has:

```
@echo off

set /p password="Enter the password for the connection: "
```

Comment: You might want to go with the decade old technology instead of the four decades old one and use PowerShell which handles this sensible out of the box.

Comment: Batch files can use `Runas` same as powershell can even if Powershell has `Get-Credential`

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to start a program as the user, please use `Runas /user:Domain\Username cmd.exe` Which will prompt for password and not display the characters typed then starts CMD.exe as the user. You can test this by using `Whoami`

More info [here](https://ss64.com/nt/runas.html)

Comment: The script will be run as root by myself and others. It's purely a security issue on client.

Comment: What OS are the clients running? That might affect the answer to this question.